# Obtain the SVM soft margin for classified data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, classification

I'm using the [`svmtrain`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) function to train the support vectors and after that the [`svmclassify`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmclassify.html) function for the classification step. This function returns the label of the class of the classified data in a binary way (0 or 1), so I can't use any confidence value for a multiclass classification.

Is there any way to obtain the soft-margin value for each classified data in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Libsvm`, that can be implemented in Matlab. You can find it at [CSIE Libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/).